# tx_metadata: How to interpret a CBOR string

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

In the document:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/tx-metadata.md

We are told: "JSON strings are represented as CBOR strings"
How can I interpret these?

The source of th eformat of those appears to be here:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7049

Here is an example of one from a transaction in the tx_metadata table of cardano-db-sync

> d8799f581c25fa506339b24dc4e1a643637325e700ae498e646746a5426739f2

[image]

...there is this:
https://github.com/CardanoSharp/CBOR

...and this:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/tx-metadata.md

...and this:
https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/user-guide/common-use-cases/TxMetadata

Answer (score 2):

A good tool for manually analyzing CBOR is https://cbor.nemo157.com/

What they probably meant by "JSON strings are represented as CBOR strings" is that typical JSON objects can be represented in tx-metadata using CBOR

Comment: I am trying to figure out how a value like this one, in the object, is a value that decodes to a wallet address:

BAED3AE13D7EEB93BB4B4F44E10AFF9F1FC052869F4A1CD1501BE928

Comment: I don't think there are any easy-to-use online tools for converting the hex of, I'm assuming, a pubkeyhash into a bech32 encoded address. You would have to use a library. Eg. with Javascript and [Helios](https://www.hyperion-bt.org/Helios-Book/api/reference/address.html#frompubkeyhash): `let isTestnet=true;helios.Address.fromPubKeyHash(isTestnet, helios.PubKeyHash.fromHex(" BAED3AE13D7EEB93BB4B4F44E10AFF9F1FC052869F4A1CD1501BE928")).toBech32()` which results in `addr_test1vzaw6whp84lwhyamfd85fcg2l703lszjs60558x32qd7j2qnwhmq3`